# Animate rotate doesn't work ie

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-animate, rotation

i already search for other posts but I couldn't find what I want. I want to user my jquery animate function with rotate. It works perfect to chrome and ff but not to ie.

```
$('#myid').animate({ rotate: '-=30deg', left: ['20%', 'easeOutQuart'], top: '20%' }, 1200);
```

Is there any solution for this or should I use other functions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE does not support rotate, you can use a polyfill like http://transformie.com or you can modifiy the filter definition yourself:

Example for 15° rotation:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(/* IE6–IE9 */ 
        M11=0.9659258262890683, M12=-0.25881904510252074, M21=0.25881904510252074, M22=0.9659258262890683, sizingMethod='auto expand');
```

Documentation for the [Matrix Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533014%28VS.85%29.aspx)